# How can I sort a data collection in ascending order on the 'sort_order' column?

Tags: collection, sorting, collection-filtering

I want to load data from a table using collection and I need the result to be in the ascending order of the 'sort_order' column which is an integer value.[image: admin form]

The above pic shows the columns in admin form.

[image: Database Table]

The above pic is of the database table.

This is the code which I used to retrieve the collection.

```
                    $collection = Mage::getModel('hm_faq/object')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('category_id',$category->getId());

                    $collection->setPageSize(5);
                    $collection->setCurPage(2);
                    $size = $collection->getSize();
                    $cnt = count($collection);
                    foreach ($collection as $button) {
                        $i = $i+1;


                ?>
                <a id="<?php echo $button->getUrlId(); ?>" href="<?php echo $button->getUrlLink(); ?>" >
                    <div  class="faq-white-button">

                        <div class="faq-inner">

                                <h3 class="faq-button-label"><?php echo $button->getUrlLabel(); ?></h3><span class="faq-icon">></span>

                        </div>

                   </div>
                </a>




            <?php echo '<br>';} ?>
```

How can i arrange the result in the ascending order of the sort_order?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with this:

```
$collection->setOrder('sort_order', 'ASC');
```